# 0 is 0 == 0 (#evaluates to True?)

Tags: python, python-3.x

This baffles me. Even without knowing the precedence order, one can check that the two possible ways to gather the expression would give `False` :

```
>>> (0 is 0) == 0
False
>>> 0 is (0 == 0)
False
```

But

```
>>> 0 is 0 == 0
True
```

How come?

Comment: This must be a dupe, but `0 is 0 == 0` is parsed as `(0 is 0) and (0 == 0)`, just like `a == b == c` is parsed as `a == b and b == c`.

Comment: @PaulHankin You should've left that as an asnwer

Comment: Check out this post: [Understanding Python's “is” operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When chaining comparison operators in Python, the operators aren't actually applied to the result of the other operators, but are applied to the operands individually. That is `x ? y ?? z` (where `?` and `??` are supposed to stand in for some comparison operators) is neither equivalent to `(x ? y) ?? z` nor `x ? (y ?? z)`, but rather `x ? y and y ?? z`.

This is particularly useful for `>` and co., allowing you to write things like `min < x < max` and have it do what you want rather than comparing a boolean to a number (which would happen in most other languages).

Answer (score 21):

You are using *comparison operator chaining*. The expression is interpreted as:

```
(0 is 0) and (0 == 0)
```

From the [*Comparisons* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).

`0 is 0` is true because [Python interns small integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2858603/why-does-the-is-keyword-have-a-different-behavior-when-there-is-a-dot-in-the-s), an implementation detail, so you get `(True) and (True)` producing `True`.